# DataTemplate is causing a memory leak when using event handlers in the code behind in UWP. Does anyone know why?

Tags: xaml, uwp, memory-leaks, datatemplate

I have a Page that has a Grid with a GridView. The GridViews ItemTemplate is set to a StaticResource DataTemplate. Within the DataTemplate I have several Bindings to data type properties but I also hook the DoubleTapped and RightTapped events from the DataTemplate Grid control to handlers that live in the code behind of the page. This set up causes the page to never get GC'd.

If I remove those events from the DataTemplate OR put the handler methods directly in the data type object itself, GC works fine and the page gets picked up.

Any idea why hooking those events up to handlers living in the code behind would cause this page to never get GC'd? Is this possibly some red herring and the problem is likely elsewhere? Below is the DataTemplate.

- UPDATE 12/8/2020 - So not only do the above solutions work to get the page picked up by GC, I just found that using a data template selector will also correct the issue (frees the page for GC)! I still don't understand why the presence of the event in the data template causes the issue or why any of these work arounds fixes the issue. I'm hoping someone out there might have an explanation. Also, this issue is not unique to GridView. I've also found it to occur when using the template for a ListView and NavigationView.

  ```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
            <Grid Name="MyGrid" Margin="0" IsDoubleTapEnabled="True" DoubleTapped="OnDoubleTapped"  RightTapped="OnRightTapped">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Border x:Name="MyBorder" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush}" Padding="0" 
                        Height="{Binding BorderHeight, Mode=OneWay}" Width="{Binding BorderWidth, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Image x:Name="Thumbnail" Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding ThumbnailToDisplay, Mode=OneWay}" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="0" 
                           Visibility="Visible" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip, Mode=OneWay}" 
                           RenderTransform="{Binding ThumbnailTransformer, Mode=OneWay}"  
                           RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
                </Border>

                <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           Margin="0"
                           Padding="0"
                           Text="{Binding PositionString, Mode=OneWay}"
                           TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                           Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}"
                           Visibility="{Binding MyTextBlockVisibility, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"
                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
  ```

Comment: Generally, an object will be released when there are no more references to it. If you put the handlers in the page code-behind, it means the page is used, it won't be released. Try to remove the handlers when you navigate to other pages to see if the page will be released.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your meaning. I believe what you're saying is that having event handler methods in the page code-behind will keep a page from being GC'd. I feel as though this cannot be true, otherwise, every page that used a handler in the code behind would suffer from the same issue which they do not. Those should be weak references and when the page is navigated away from, it is removed from the visual tree at which time it becomes eligible for GC.

Comment: You could make a simple try to confirm this. Remove the handlers before you leave the page and see if the same behavior happens.